# Sending a 301/302 redirect from a Python CGI script

Tags: python, http-headers, cgi, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I keep finding answers on how to read a redirect from an HTTP client response out of Python, but I can't figure out how to send a 301 or 302 redirect back to the client.  Seems this should work, but I always get a 200 response before the body:

```
print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n")
print("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently")
print("Location:", "https://www.google.com/")
```

The equivalent PHP code would simply be:

```
// Redirect the browser to Google
header("Location: https://www.google.com/", true, 301);
```

Comment: What libraries are you using? Python is more "generally general-purpose" than PHP and doesn't assume it's running as a web service.

Comment: At the time of this post, I was really using no libraries or frameworks.  this is just plain jane CGI, not even WSGI, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's simplest form, with no external libraries, you can simply output straight HTTP:

```
print('''Status: 301 Redirect
Location: {url}
Content-Type: text/html

Moved permanently to <a href="{url}">{url}</a>
'''.format(url='https://www.google.com/'))
```

If you are using a library or framework there are likely better approaches.